# Why doesn't the generator return the following value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For each call to the "loop" function, I try to return a new value of the "c" property from the "test" object, but for some reason, I get the same value of every function call.

```
1 call: {value: {a: 1}, done: false}
2 call: {value: {a: 1}, executed: false}
3 call: {value: {a: 1}, done: false}
```

instead of getting a new value for every call

```
1 call: {value: {a: 1}, done: false}
2 call: {value: {a: 2}, executed: false}
3 call: {value: {a: 3}, done: true}
```

```js
const test = {
  a: { id: 1 },
  b: { id: 2 },
  c: [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
};

function* generLoop(elem) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-restricted-syntax
  for (el of test[elem]) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    yield el;
  }
}

const createLoop = elem => {
  const gen = generLoop(elem);
  return () => gen.next();
};

function loop(elem) {
  const findQuery = Object.keys(test).find(el => el === elem);
  if (findQuery) {
    const loopIterator = createLoop('c');
    loopIterator();
  }
  return test[elem];
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(loop('c'));
}
```

In fact, this is a simulation of the logic that I want to implement. In reality, I imitate the response of the server when the names of the requests come, I want to give a certain set of data, but some requests will come several times and ask for the same data structure but with different values, so the function "loop" will be called independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a generator only once, and then call `next()` as you need

```
cosnt createLoop = elem => {
  const findQuery = Object.keys(test).find(el => el === elem);
  let gen
  if (findQuery) {
    gen = generLoop('c');
  }
  return () => gen ? gen.next() : test[elem];
}

const iterator = createLoop('c')
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(iterator());
}
```

Comment: thx, but I will get an argument "c" only in function "loop" parameters, so it's a challenge pass this argument to variable scope  "generator"

Comment: Seems like closure is way to go, can be something like that: `const createLoop = elem => { const gen = createGen(elem); return () => gen.next() }` and then when you want to call it `const loopIterator = createLoop('c'); loopIterator();` and after some time `loopIterator()`. I hope I got your point right :)

Comment: in that case this will return 
`[ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
[ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]
[ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { c: 3 } ]`
Also i refactored my question regarding to you answer